# Compare data in two RDD in spark

Tags: apache-spark, scala-2.10, cloudera-cdh, rdd

I am able to print data in two RDD with the below code.

```
usersRDD.foreach(println)
empRDD.foreach(println)
```

I need to compare data in two RDDs. How can I iterate and compare field data in one RDD with field data in another RDD. Eg: iterate the records and check if name and age in `userRDD` has a matching record in `empRDD`, if no put in separate RDD.

I tried with `userRDD.substract(empRDD)` but it was comparing all the fields.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to key the data in each RDD so that there is something to join records on. Have a look at `groupBy` for example. Then you `join` the resulting RDDs. For each key, you get the matching values in both. If you are interested in finding the unmatched keys, use `leftOuterJoin`, like this:

```
// Returns the entries in userRDD that have no corresponding key in empRDD.
def nonEmp(userRDD: RDD[(String, String)], empRDD: RDD[(String, String)]) = {
  userRDD.leftOuterJoin(empRDD).collect {
    case (name, (age, None)) => name -> age
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like OP may be interested in finding keys that are present in one RDD and missing from the other. For this, you need `leftOuterJoin` instead of `join`. May be worth mentioning in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Sean, but i need to find the unmatching data from the two RDDs. it will be great, if you provide sample code.

Comment: Ah thanks @DanielDarabos, that's the right answer. I misread the original text.

Comment: @Ramakrishna, I've added an example with `leftOuterJoin`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Of course the above solutions are complete and correct! Just one proposal , if and only if the RDDs are synchronized(Same rows have the same keys). You can use a distributed solution and exploit parallelism by using only spark transformations via the following tested solution:

```
def distrCompare(left: RDD[(Int,Int)], right: RDD[(Int,Int)]): Boolean = {
  val rdd1 = left.join(right).map{case(k, (lv,rv)) => (k,lv-rv)}
  val rdd2 = rdd1.filter{case(k,v)=>(v!=0)}
  var equal = true;
  rdd2.map{
    case(k,v)=> if(v!=0) equal = false
  }
  return equal
}
```

You can choose the number of partitions in "join".