# Compare two rdd's to identify audit fields change and corresponding field names

Tags: scala, apache-spark, compare, rdd

I was trying to compare two files generated from two different sources(ideally both files should have same data). which has almost 300 fields and trying to generate a report of fields have different values. Could you please suggest best possible way of identifying the records with field name having different values.
Both row and field name for the difference in values

we can use subtract transformation on rdd or outer join using DF/rdd but unable to identify the field names as well.

Appreciate your help if any!

Regards,
Scala Learner

Comment: I think you have already tried this [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782923/compare-data-in-two-rdd-in-spark) and you are not getting field names as report isnt it ?

Comment: Yes Ram. We are able to identify the differences of fields via subtract or Join but unable to populate only fields that with difference in value.

Comment: would be great if you put the example code snippet of what you have done and what you are expecting  and what you are getting